# Ionic: I want storing authetication token only in an encrypted form, using a secure encryption key from the Android keystore, and the iOS keychain

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, keychain, capacitor

Previously, I had used capacitor storage to store authorization token using ionic, The tokens, which are stored in plain text in the file system. On Android this is the binary file app_webview/Default/IndexedDB
/http_localhost_0.indexeddb.leveldb/000003.log within the application data. On iOS the table
“Records” in the SQLite database at Library/WebKit/WebsiteData/IndexedDB/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0/v0
/v0/v0/v0/v0/v1/capacitor_localhost_0/77600FECA837AAF0809BAEDA2D9AE13D4C6127153
1CB15BF2560D2C6346FE4AC/IndexedDB.sqlite3 is being used.

A disadvantage of doing so is :

When having administrative access to the devices, these tokens can easily be extracted from the file and used in other contexts.

Want to implement a way is:
storing login data only in an encrypted form, using a secure encryption key from the
Android Keystore, and the iOS keychain.

In React-native there is a plugin like react-native-encrypted-storage  which was able to set and get data in keychain // Keystore in an encrypted format but I don't find any way for ionic,

Comment: I am in the same boat. Did you find any plugin which supports secure storage in ionic for both platforms?